# Loop to get image srcs to populate dynamic sharing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to "inject" (might be the wrong word) code for social media sharing links after each image on a page. I've got the "injection" part working but all my image source variables are just the last image.

My goal is to have the jQuery create a div with social media share links that reference the image right before the links in the code. (it'll make more sense when you see the code.)

HTML Code:

```
<section id="photos">
    <a href="/alt/img/portfolio/andy-600x900.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
        <img class="img-responsive" itemprop="image" src="/alt/img/portfolio/andy-395x593.jpg" alt="Andy's Portrait" />
    </a>    

    <a href="/alt/img/portfolio/asbury-park-1500x1000.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox"> 
        <img class="img-responsive" itemprop="image" src="/alt/img/portfolio/asbury-park-400x267.jpg" alt="Asbury Park" />
    </a>

    <a href="/alt/img/portfolio/dice-600x900.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
        <img class="img-responsive" itemprop="image" src="/alt/img/portfolio/dice-395x592.jpg" alt="Dice product shot" />
    </a>
</section>
```

JQUERY Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 736) {

        $('.img-responsive').each(function() {
            imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

        var twitter="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social twitter' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"&text=Check out this photo from Example Photography&hashtags=photos' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var facebook="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social facebook' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var google="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social gPlus' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var pinterest="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social pinterest' href='http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"&description=' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>"; 
        social = "<div class='socialContainer'>"+twitter+facebook+google+pinterest+"</div>";
        });
        $('#photos a').each(function () {
            $(this).after(social);
        });

    }
});
```

Here's a working Demo (well, really a not working demo), https://jsfiddle.net/w0tknfb6/, with all the relevant CSS and stuff.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need few small changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 736) {
social=[]; //create array
        $('.img-responsive').each(function() {
            imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

        var twitter="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social twitter' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"&text=Check out this photo from Example Photography&hashtags=photos' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var facebook="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social facebook' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var google="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social gPlus' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>";
        var pinterest="<a rel='external nofollow' class='social pinterest' href='http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://www.example.com"+imgSrc+"&description=' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;\"></a>"; 
        social.push("<div class='socialContainer'>"+twitter+facebook+google+pinterest+"</div>"); //push values

        });
          $('#photos a').each(function (i) {
            $(this).after(social[i]); //add values 
        });
        // NOT WORKING
        $('#photos a').on('click', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).find('.socialContainer').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w0tknfb6/10/

Explanation: After first each() loop you are using social variable, and, as expected, you have just one/last value available. This way, by creating array, and push all values in it, you can use it for new each loop (#photos a loop), and 'inject' it to body... Changes commented in code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been killing me for days.